# DateTimePicker wont update the value field onChange or onSelect

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to update the value of an input when i change the selected date. 
This is my html code for the input.

```
<input type="text" name="completed_date" id="completed_date" size="12" class="completed_date fielddate" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime("now"))?>" readonly />
```

This is my jquery onSelect function

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.completed_date').datetimepicker({
   timepicker: false,
   format: 'd/m/Y',
    onSelect: function() {
     var date = $(this).val();
     $('#completed_date').val(date);
    }
  });
 });
```

This code has no effect on my input field but if i change the last line to

```
$('#completed_date').text(date);
```

then it adds the new selected date to the end of the html line.

`<input type="text" name="completed_date" id="completed_date" size="12" class="completed_date fielddate" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime("now"))?>" readonly />` ***Adds the date here***

The code in the value field currently shows today's date by default but should be updated onSelect.

I have read the documentation but cant seem to find what im missing.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

It updates visually in the field but the actual value in the input doesn't change so when i click save it always sends today's date instead of the selected date

Comment: I don't understand what the real *question* is.. Doesn't it update when you select a new date in the datepicker? That should be default behaviour.

Comment: why you want set it manually which it does itself?

Comment: It updates visually in the field but the actual value in the input doesn't change so when i click save it always sends todays date instead of the selected date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap-datepicker use .datepicker method to load the picker.

```js
$('.completed_date').datepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'d/m/yy'      
  })
.on("changeDate", function(e) {
 
  $('#completed_date').attr('value', e.format());
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" name="completed_date" id="completed_date" size="12" class="completed_date fielddate" value="12/12/2016" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :).  This is a different plugin to the one i am currently using which i dont mind changing but from what i can see when i inspect this code when you change the date the value field doesn't update which is the exact same issue im having with mine. is this something you have come across before?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I updated the answer, now the value attribute is updating (this should be it)

Comment: Thank you - Yes its working perfectly on your snippet now. I am still struggling to get it to work on my system for some reason but yours works great :)

Comment: use change event will help for timepicker

Answer (score 1):

Firstly thank you for all your help.

I have just used your code and edited it slightly and i have managed to get your solution to work with the DateTimePicker. I have included the code below.
Once again many thanks.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.completed_date').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'d/m/Y',
 });
 $('.completed_date').change(function() {
    var date = $(this).val();
    $('.completed_date').attr('value', date);
 });

});
```

This will update the value field on an input linked to the DateTimePicker.